# unity build settings for android unchangeable after reimporting assets

Tags: unity-game-engine

Recently, I've been trying to get Unity Remote 5 to work on my computer, and after realizing that it would be a lot harder than I originally thought, I began searching through forums for answers. One of the solutions proposed that I reimport all assets, but upon doing so and then going back to build settings, the tab for the android section in the build settings was in a completely different layout (as pictured below).
[picture of android layout i'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INREx.png)

On top of this, I can't tick any of these check boxes or change any settings in the layout at all. Forgive me if there's a super simple solution to this (as I'm still a beginner), but I've wasted many hours trying to find a solution, and I'm not sure if this is a bug or simply a misunderstanding. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which version of unity are you using?

Comment: unity 2019.3.0a4, personal edition